# How to get post permalink url without a href

Tags: php, permalinks, links

I need code to get post url without a href, for example: `<a href="http://mywebsite.com/permalink" rel="permalink">single post title</a>`

i just need the url like: `http://mywebsite.com/permalink/` on single.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is `get_permalink`, e.g.

```php
$current_post_url = get_permalink();
```

You can either use it inside a post loop, or pass it a post ID as a parameter.